# How to add a marker to a non-address location on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

In Google Maps, how can I have a place-marker appear for a place by using only it's coordinates?

The short code I'm currently using is:

```
[map lat="46.090271" long="6.657248" zoom="9" type="" width="670" height="350"]
```

If I could enter an address, I would be able to use the following shortcode to add a placeholder:

```
[map lat="46.090271" long="6.657248" zoom="9" type="" width="670" height="350" address="morillon, france"]
```

But I really need a more specific location to pinpoint the chalet itself.

Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `description (name) @46.090271,6.657248` as the address.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I tried this and it was of no use. In the end i have just used - address="46.090271,6.657248" which pinpoints the position with a marker - but gives the coordinates instead of address name in the display.

Comment: @Nick: http://maps.google.com/maps?q=description+(name)+%4046.090271,6.657248

Answer (score 0):

As nick says, you can just put it into URL.

However, if you need to insert multiple coordinates (as opposed to a single location), you have to use some online mapping tool, for example http://www.hamstermap.com and then choose Quick Map from the menu.

Comment: Given all the answers you gave with this rodent tool, I have a question for you: are you by any change affiliated to the rodent?